# How to merge similar type .csv files into one and count the rows (without creating new file)

Tags: bash, shell-script

Im Having 6 .csv files in my folder as aca1.csv, aca2.csv, aca3.csv, team1.csv, team2.csv and team3.csv. each file has 80,90,60,70,80 and 90 rows.. I need a bash script file where it will combine or merge files with its type for ex.. aca1,aca2,aca3 will be aca type. and Count the row values(without creating new merged file becauset i want to count the rows only). Write the Count value and Type of the file into another .csv file.. If anyone knows help me?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.  Also, if your teacher placed any special requirements on how you solve this, make them clear.

Comment: Please give examples of both input files and the expected output. Well not all 90 columns but a few to show the princip.

Comment: What you mean by row values? 1,2,3 and 2,3,4 will give a row with 6 and a row of 9 or just count the rows per file pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below as a bash script which works for files named as `<pattern><number>.<extension>` like abc1.csv, abc02.csv, abc123.csv.
You can optionally provide the input directory (default: .) as the first command line argument and the file extension (default: csv) as the second; of course, you will have to compulsorily specify $1 if you want to specify $2.

```
$ cat ./countlinesbyfilecategory.sh
#!/bin/bash

ptrns=$(for fnm in `find ${1:-.} -regex ".*[0-9][0-9]*\.${2:-csv}"`; do echo $fnm | sed "s/[0-9][0-9]*\.${2:-csv}$//" ; done| sort -u)

for ptrn in $ptrns; do
        echo -n $(basename $ptrn) " "
        find ${1:-.} -regex "${ptrn}[0-9][0-9]*\.${2:-csv}" | xargs wc -l | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
done

$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the following that uses `wc` `awk` and a while `loop` and iterate over different patterns since you want to count the rows only:

```
n=0
while read i
do 
((n=n+$i))
done <<(wc -l aca* | awk '{print $1}')
echo $n;
```

`wc -l aca* | awk '{print $1}'` will give you the number of lines per file of the pattern.
`while` reading the above output you will get the `n` value that is zero and add recursivly the output of `wc`
at last you print the total lines.

for logging the type and rows you youc script it and put as input the pattern you want to measure then `echo "$pattern $n" >> output.txt`

```
user@server[/apps/home/user/]>  cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

for p in "aca*" "*sh"
do
n=0;
while read i;
 do ((n=n+$i));
 done < <(wc -l $p | awk '{print $1}'); echo "$p" $n;
done

user@server[/apps/home/user/]> bash script.sh
aca* 46
*sh 432
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you need the rowcounts of all the types in one or 
in separate csv files.

If you need two different csv files, then use,

```
sh-4.3$ for i in aca team
do 
i_ct=`awk -v pat=$i -F ',' 'BEGIN{c=0} FILENAME ~ pat {c += NF}END{print c}' *.csv`
echo "$i,${i_ct}" > ${i}_count.csv 
done
```

If you need type and rowcount of both "test" and "aca"  in one file

```
sh-4.3$ for i in aca team 
do 
i_ct=`awk -v pat=$i -F ',' 'BEGIN{c=0} FILENAME ~ pat {c += NF}END{print c}' *.csv`
echo "$i,${i_ct}" 
done  > All_ftype_count.csv
```

If there are more file types, you can add it after team in `for i in` . Do share your feedback.